# Loop through all media library images and return those where caption contains the text carousel

Tags: loop, media, media-library

Im new to Wordpress but I'm looking for a way to loop through all the images that have been uploaded to the media library and output the SRC, description and caption of the image when the caption contains the word 'carousel'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this pretty easily with a simple query:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND meta_value LIKE '%carousel%'");
foreach($results as $result){
    //$result->post_id will give you the original attachment post
}
```